# adding multiple data into a model using serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

the below code is the object in which the dummy data is stored and to be added into the database.

```
obj = [
    {
        "activity_name": 'test-for-33',
        "created_by": 1142,
        "activity_start": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 ",
        "activity_end": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 "

    },
    {
        "activity_name": "test-for-55",
        "created_by": "1142",
        "activity_start": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 ",
        "activity_end": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 "


    }
]
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def insert_data_activity(request):
    # Check if seats is a list
    # if isinstance(request.data['seat'], list):
    #     seats = request.data.pop('seat')
    if obj is not None:
        models = []
        for i in obj:
            # validate each model with one seat at a time
            print(i['activity_name'])
            request.data['i.activity_name'] = i['activity_name']
            serializer = ActivitySerializer(data=request.data)
            serializer.activity_name = i['activity_name']
            print("msmssmmmmmmmmmmmmmmm", serializer.activity_name)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
            print("saved")
            models.append(serializer)
        # Save it only after all seats are valid.
        # To avoid situations when one seat has wrong id
        # And you already save previous
        saved_models = [model.save() for model in models]
        result_serializer = ActivitySerializer(saved_models, many=True)
        # Return list of tickets
        return Response(result_serializer.data)
    # Save ticket as usual
    serializer = ActivitySerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

here the model is getting updated with the object but it is taking null as an input and storing it into the database as shown below.

```
{
    "id": 39,
    "activity_name": null,
    "acttivity_start": null,
    "activity_end": null,
    "created": "2018-10-11T05:39:17.329655Z",
    "modified": "2018-10-11T05:39:17.329671Z",
    "created_by": null
}
```

Comment: Include your ActivitySerializer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few problems with your implementation.

1. `obj` is not defined
2. replacing activity_name with 'i.activity_name' in request data
3. adding manually activity_name field to the serializer
4. multiple save calls
5. not handling GET request
6. it seems to be handling one as well as many when you try to POST ( even though the one is not saved ).
7. not clear what data you actually send.

So, I assume that the data you send looks like this:

```
 {
"obj": [{
        "activity_name": "st-for-33",
        "created_by": 1142,
        "activity_start": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 ",
        "activity_end": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 "
    },
    {
        "activity_name": "st-for-33",
        "created_by": 1142,
        "activity_start": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 ",
        "activity_end": "2018-10-10 07:56:11+00 "
    }
]
}
```

The implementation could look like this:

```
@api_view(['POST', 'GET'])
@parser_classes((JSONParser,))
def insert_data_activity(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        # decide what to do in case of GET
        return Response({"data" : "something"})
    obj = request.data.pop('obj', None)
    if obj is not None:         
         ser = ActivitySerializer(data=obj, many=True)
         ser.is_valid()
         ser.save()
         return Response(ser.data)
    # Save ticket as usual
    serializer = ActivitySerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

This implementation supports one or many. Also this depends how your serializer is implemented but I assume standard ModelSerializer with `__all__` fields.

Comment: without using a for loop how its gonna add multiple data? please help me with a proper code which add n number of data . you have only used if conditions here.i have used __all__ in serializers.

Comment: thank you for your help the multiple data are adding but i am getting no values in it. {"id": 11,
        "activity_id": null,
        "grade": null,
        "branch": null,
        "section": null,
        "subject": null} i have used it for different view kindly help.